# how to do an in-place sort of a linked list in Java to add objects containing integers in ascending order?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have a linked list containing objects of type student, with name(string) and ID (integer). I have an insertInOrder method. if I only use this method, all the objects are added in order...1,2,3,4, etc. but if I want to add another object to a linked list which wasn't created in order, I need to sort it.
can someone tell me how I can fix this?

so If have students with IDs 8, 5,9,3 and use this method, my linkedlist is sorted. but if use a method like insert_to_front or insert_to_end, and then want to add a student with ID 7, linkedlist should get sorted before adding...right?

```
 public void insertInOrder(Student s) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = s;
    } else if (s.getId() == head.getId()) {
        return;

    } else if (s.getId() < head.getId()) {
        insertToFrontofList(s);
    } else {
        Student c2 = head;
        Student c1 = head;
        while (c2.getNext() != null) {
            c1 = c2;
            c2 = c2.getNext();

            if (s.getId() < c2.getId()) {
                c1.setNext(s);
                s.setNext(c2);
                return;
            } else if (s.getId() == c2.getId()) {
                return;
            }
        }
        insertToEnd(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are literally asking to override `addFirst()` , `addLast()` methods, why don't you add everything and sort next

Comment: All i want to do is....get the linkedlist, then create an empty list, then one by one get the items of the linkedlist and by using this method (insert in order....) put these items in order